# Elastic Search return object with sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get a list of the top 100 guests by revenue generated with Elastic Search. To do this I am using a `terms` and a `sum` aggregation. However it does return the correct values, I wan to return the entire `guest` object with the aggregation.

This is my query:

```json
GET reservations/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "top_revenue": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "total",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "top_revenue_hits": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_revenue_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns a list of the top 100 guests but only the amount they spent:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "top_revenue" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 498,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 934.9500122070312,
          "doc_count" : 8,
          "top_revenue_hits" : {
          "value" : 7479.60009765625
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 922.0,
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "top_revenue_hits" : {
          "value" : 5532.0
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the query to return the entire `guests` object, not only the sum amount.

When I run `GET reservations/_search` it returns:

```json
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "reservations",
      "_id": "1334620",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "id": "1334620",
        "total": 110.8,
        "payment": "unpaid",
        "contact": {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "email": "john@mail.com"
        }
      }
    },
    ... other reservations
  ]
}
```

I want to get this to return with the `sum` aggregation.

I have tried to use a `top_hits` aggregation, using `_source` it does return the entire `guest` object but it does not show the total amount spent. And when adding `_source` to the `sum` aggregation it gives an error.

Can I return the entire `guest` object with a `sum` aggregation or is this not the correct way?

Comment: Your query doesnot match with yours question. In your question your first aggreation group by total, not by guest. So in your response you have 8 reservations with a total price of 934.95 each => sum price 8*934.95 => 7479.
You sure you dont want to aggregate by "contact.email' and made a subaggregation on total instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that `contact.name` is `keyword` in the mapping. Following query should work for you.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "guests": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "contact.name",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total"
          }
        },
        "sortBy": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              { "sum_total": { "order": "desc" } } 
            ]
          }
        },
        "guest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work, but still only returns the `sum_total` value. Is there a way to return the entire object in the aggregation? I just started using elastic so I do not know much about it.

Comment: I updated the answer, is it what you want?